# In AngularJS, how to correctly display embeded iframe using ng-bind-html and $sce?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have this embeded code that I get through an AJAX request:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/80836225?badge=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then, in a controller I try to assign it to a variable so that it renders in the HTML. I'm using $sce.trushAsHtml and in the HTML I am using ng-bing-html.

What I do in the controller is something like this. After I GET the response from the request, I assign the iframe string to a var called myIframe and then make it go through $sce.trushAsHtml. So:

**Controller**

```
var myIframe = ...response from GET (the <iframe> string above)
$scope.preview = $sce.trustAsHtml(myIframe);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-bind-html="preview"></div>
```

I do get to display the video, but I also get this error in the console:

```
Error: a.indexOf is not a function
z@http://mydomain/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js:7
@http://mydomain/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js:12
@http://mydomain/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js:12
h.prototype.$digest@http://mydomain/angular/angular.min.js:100
h.prototype.$apply@http://mydomain/angular/angular.min.js:103
f@http://mydomain/angular/angular.min.js:67
E@http://mydomain/angular/angular.min.js:71
pd/</v.onreadystatechange@http://mydomain/angular/angular.min.js:72
```

I want to get rid of this error. I suspect it has something to do with the $digest cycle in angularjs, but don't know how to fix it. Any idea on why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I believe I found the problem. I updated angularjs version but I was still using an older ngSanitize version. Updated to latest and the error is gonne.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. The angular.js and angular-sanitize.js files need to be the same version!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was only due to an error on the programmer's side using old version of library.

Comment: Programmer's side "errors" are pretty common and - as humans - very natural. Also, given the pace of how AngularJS grows and changes, it could be that someone else faces the same problem without realizing. More, if you're a programmer picking up on someone else's project and you have to implement new functionality then you could end up having files with different versions. I think it's good to have an answer on why things happen, but maybe that's just me.